# How to increment variable whenever a method is called

Tags: java

I am just in learning phase & here I am using some polymorphism technique. This is the code:

```
package com.company;
class Car{
    private String name;
    private int cylinder;
    private boolean engine;
    private int wheels;

    public Car(String name, int cylinder) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cylinder = cylinder;
        this.engine = true;
        this.wheels = 4;
    }

    public String startEngine(int fuel){
        if(fuel>0){
            return "Start button pressed";
        } else{
            return "First fill some fuel";
        }
    }

    public String accelerate(int speed){
        return "Car is accelerated with speed " + speed;
    }

    public String brake(int speed){
        return "Brake is presses. Now speed is " + speed;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getCylinder() {
        return cylinder;
    }
}

class Fortuner extends Car{
    public Fortuner() {
        super("Fortuner", 4);
    }

    @Override
    public String accelerate(int speed) {
        return "Fortuner is accelerated with speed " +speed;
    }

    @Override
    public String brake(int speed) {
        return "Now your Fortuner is moving with " + speed + " kph";
    }
}

class Hondacity extends Car{
    public Hondacity() {
        super("Hinda City", 6);
    }

    @Override
    public String accelerate(int speed) {
        return "Honda City is accelerated with speed " +speed;
    }

    @Override
    public String brake(int speed) {
        return "Now your Honda City is moving with " + speed + " kph";
    }
}

class Omni extends Car{
    public Omni() {
        super("Omni", 1);
    }

    @Override
    public String accelerate(int speed) {
        return "Omni is accelerated with speed " +speed;
    }

    @Override
    public String brake(int speed) {
        return "Now your Omni is moving with " + speed + " kph";
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
            Car car = speedup();
            System.out.println(car.accelerate(50));
        }

    }

    public static Car speedup() {
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            switch(i){
                case 0: return new Fortuner();
                case 1: return new Hondacity();
                case 2: return new Omni();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

When I run it, it's giving output like this:

> Fortuner is accelerated with speed 50 Fortuner is accelerated with
>   speed 50 Fortuner is accelerated with speed 50

But I want to give output something like this

> Fortuner is accelerated with speed 50 Hondacity is accelerated with
>   speed 50 Omni is accelerated with speed 50

I know this is happening due to initialization each time when method runs. How can I solve it? Please apologize me for poor algorithm as I am just a learner.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You have posted way to much code in your question, which makes it unclear to us (and to future readers) exactly where the problem is.  Please reduce your problem code to 10 lines or less.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `speedup()` always returns a Fortuner, as it never gets any further. The `return` command always exits the loop. So if you want to get all the classes, you would have to do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     for(int ID=0; ID<3; ID++){
         Car car = speedup(ID);
         System.out.println(car.accelerate(50));
     }

}

public static Car speedup(int ID) {
     switch(i){
     case 0: return new Fortuner();
     case 1: return new Hondacity();
     case 2: return new Omni();
     }
     return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Duke! You made it very simple. Can you please tell me how do you develop algorithm. I mean how can I improve this.

Comment: @Brijesh Maurya I'm still learning java as well. You will see, there are some rules how java works. One example is, that `return` always finishes the current method. The more you practise programming, the more of those rules youwill learn and with every rule you will understand better, what is going on in your program. It's an amazing feeling actually, so just keep on learning ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your method speedup() the value of j each time is 0. so it always return Fortuner. I have removed this method to solve it.

```
class Car {
        private String name;
        private int cylinder;
        private boolean engine;
        private int wheels;

        public Car(String name, int cylinder) {
            this.name = name;
            this.cylinder = cylinder;
            this.engine = true;
            this.wheels = 4;
        }

        public Car() {
        }

        public String startEngine(int fuel){
            if(fuel>0){
                return "Start button pressed";
            } else{
                return "First fill some fuel";
            }
        }

        public String accelerate(int speed){
            return "Car is accelerated with speed " + speed;
        }

        public String brake(int speed){
            return "Brake is presses. Now speed is " + speed;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getCylinder() {
            return cylinder;
        }
    }

    class Fortuner extends Car{
        public Fortuner() {
            super("Fortuner", 4);
        }

        @Override
        public String accelerate(int speed) {
            return "Fortuner is accelerated with speed " +speed;
        }

        @Override
        public String brake(int speed) {
            return "Now your Fortuner is moving with " + speed + " kph";
        }
    }

    class Hondacity extends Car{
        public Hondacity() {
            super("Hinda City", 6);
        }

        @Override
        public String accelerate(int speed) {
            return "Honda City is accelerated with speed " +speed;
        }

        @Override
        public String brake(int speed) {
            return "Now your Honda City is moving with " + speed + " kph";
        }
    }

    class Omni extends Car{
        public Omni() {
            super("Omni", 1);
        }

        @Override
        public String accelerate(int speed) {
            return "Omni is accelerated with speed " +speed;
        }

        @Override
        public String brake(int speed) {
            return "Now your Omni is moving with " + speed + " kph";
        }
    }

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
                Car car = null;
                switch (j) {
                case 0: car = new Fortuner();
                    break;
                case 1: car = new Hondacity();
                    break;
                case 2: car = new Omni();
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(car.accelerate(50));
            }

        }

    }
```